# Rabbitmq listener using pika in django

Tags: django, rabbitmq, pika

I have a django application and I want to consume messages from a rabbit mq. I want the listener to start consuming when I start the django server.I am using pika library to connect to rabbitmq.Proving some code example will really help.

Comment: add what you have tried.

Comment: I have an example for Flask and pika, but maybe it can get you started.
https://github.com/eandersson/python-rabbitmq-examples/blob/master/Flask-examples/pika_async_rpc_example.py

Answer (score 10):

First you need to somehow run your application at the start of the django project
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready

```
def ready(self):
    if not settings.IS_ACCEPTANCE_TESTING and not settings.IS_UNITTESTING:
        consumer = AMQPConsuming()
        consumer.daemon = True
        consumer.start()
```

Further in any convenient place

```
import threading

import pika
from django.conf import settings


class AMQPConsuming(threading.Thread):
    def callback(self, ch, method, properties, body):
        # do something
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def _get_connection():
        parameters = pika.URLParameters(settings.RABBIT_URL)
        return pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)

    def run(self):
        connection = self._get_connection()
        channel = connection.channel()

        channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue6')
        print('Hello world! :)')

        channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        channel.basic_consume(self.callback, queue='queue')

        channel.start_consuming()
```

This will help
http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html

Comment: I build this code, the method run is called. I publish in one queue the outher service process my message and return the message but not consumed by python

Comment: I have a question @Alexander, Can we do channel.stop_consuming from somewhere else if we run it in a thread?

Comment: @SanjeevSiva, now I realize that as a "production-ready" solution, it's a bad idea.

A good idea is to raise the second instance of the application as celery does.

For example:
`./manage.py runserver  # to start http server in the first terminal`
and 
`./manage.py runconsuming  # to start listener in the second terminal`

Comment: @Alexander, that's an interesting way to look at it.

I have a different problem 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61651947/rabbitmq-pika-and-django-channels-websocket/61671786#61671786

Do you mind checking it out?